# ITextsharp HTML to PDF, display:inline-block not working

Tags: c#, css, itext

I'm trying to convert a section of an HTML file to a PDF file but found out that `display:inline-block` isn't working after the conversion. I tried to create a sample html with few elements to test this out:

```
<span>1</span><br><span></span></a></div>&nbsp;<div class="seat"><a data-seat-no="2" class="btn-seat seat-crew" href="#!">
<span>2</span><br><span></span></a></div>&nbsp;<div class="spacing"></div>&nbsp;<div class="seat"><a data-seat-no="3" class="btn-seat seat-crew" href="#!">
<span>3</span><br><span></span></a></div>&nbsp;<div class="seat"><a data-seat-no="4" class="btn-seat seat-crew" href="#!">
<span>4</span><br><span></span></a></div>&nbsp;<br><div class="seat"><a data-seat-no="5" class="btn-seat" href="#!">
<span>5</span><br><span></span></a></div>&nbsp;<div class="seat"><a data-seat-no="6" class="btn-seat" href="#!">
<span>6</span><br><span></span></a></div>&nbsp;<div class="spacing"></div>&nbsp;<div class="seat"><a data-seat-no="7" class="btn-seat" href="#!">
<span>7</span><br><span></span></a></div>&nbsp;<div class="seat"><a data-seat-no="8" class="btn-seat" href="#!">
<span>8</span><br><span></span></a></div>&nbsp;<br><div class="seat"><a data-seat-no="9" class="btn-seat" href="#!">
<span>9</span><br><span></span></a></div>&nbsp;<div class="seat"><a data-seat-no="10" class="btn-seat" href="#!">
<span>10</span><br><span></span></a></div>&nbsp;<div class="spacing"></div>&nbsp;
```

and the CSS code is:

```
.seat {
    background: #1f89c0 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 87px;
}
```

`display:inline-block` works whenever I render this in a browser:

[image]

But when I tried to convert it to a PDF file, the result is:

[image]

Doesn't ItextSharp know how to render `display:inline-block`? Do I really have to use floats?

Comment: Are you using HTMLWorker or XMLWorker?

Comment: Also, please understand that PDF doesn't have a concept called "floating", only absolutely positioned items. To say that again, if you think of PDF from an HTML/CSS perspective (which has many flaws), PDF only supports `position: absolute;` for everything. iText has a helper library dedicated to converting HTML relative concepts into absolute PDF concepts but it is by no means a full-fledged ACID compliant browser. iText excels at allowing you to easily create 100% custom PDFs but if you're just looking for exact HTML representation you might want to look at something like wkhtmltopdf